# Can I force filepath.Abs to give path deisgned for another OS?

Tags: go, filepath

I currently am working on Windows. I use the following code to get an absolute path for a relative path.

```
absolutePath, err := filepath.Abs(relativePath)
```

The output for this is `C:\project\test`. Is there any way to "trick" `filepath.Abs` to have a Linux style absolute path, whether it's `/project/test` or `/d/project/test/`? Thanks!

Comment: You can't determine the absolute path on a system when you're not on that system. Are you looking for something more like [`path.Clean`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Clean)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JimB noted, converting a relative path to an absolute path is not only OS-specific, it's context-specific: the same relative path on different systems (regardless of OS) can yield different paths; in fact, even on *the same system*, converting relative to absolute from different working directories can yield different paths. Again as @JimB noted, you can use [`path.Clean`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Clean) to remove any unnecessary or reduntant relative path components (e.g. turn `/dir/../otherDir/./subDir/` into `/otherDir/subDir/`), but that's the closest you'll get to anything not context-sensitive.

If you just want to convert the *representation*, there's [`filepath.ToSlash`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#ToSlash) which will replace all platform-specific separators with forward slashes. If you're trying to re-use a path across systems, you could run `ToSlash` on the input, store the "generic" path using forward slashes, then on the target system use [`filepath.FromSlash`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#FromSlash) to convert it back to the platform-specific path separator.

Comment: `filepath.ToSlash` is the closest I got to do what I wanted. In the end, a filepath like C:/project/test was created. Just a matter of removing the semicolon and prepending /. Thanks.